# 2D Space filling curves with Bit Twiddlings 64bits

Tags: c, 64-bit, hilbert-curve, z-order-curve

Are there any space filling curves that can be calculated(indexes) with Bit Twiddling , different from neutral(simple shift), Morton(Binary Magic Numbers), and Hilbert(from Morton) ? Any examples with encode(xy2d)/decode(d2xy) ?